# Not able to add fields to my content type in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

In my localhost drupal site I have created a content type "Scholarship". Now I need to add few more fields (checkboxes, radio etc) to it.

The problem is, I cannot see "Add new fields" option anywhere on the page. When I click the "Manage Fields" options I am redirected to the "content/node-type/scholarship/fields" and there is no option for adding new fields.

It was working initially, but after a while it stopped. I disabled Panels and few other modules that I think might have caused the problem. But it still does not show

Any idea on what is causing this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Which theme you're using ?

Comment: It take it you cleared caches ? Can you add fields on other content types ?

Comment: I am using Garden theme at the admin side and yes I am clearing the caches. The issue I am facing is that when I click "manage fields" it takes me to the "fields" page where I cannot see any "add fields" option. All I see is three columns separated by vertical black lines. In the first column I have my existing fields of that content type which I can remove or configure (but cannot add any new), in the other columns all I see is a Add a field "text" hanging around. I wish there was someway I could show you guys what I see in that page.